# How to find out that majority points in a range are lying on left side, right side or central area of values in a another vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, range

How to find out that majority points in a range are lying on left side, right side or central area of values in another vector in MATLAB?
e.g. i have one set of value range such as [99 143], and i want to check whether majority of these points are located on which side of another range such as [97 190]. The result of above is left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compute the median, and test to see which end of the target range it is close to.
call `median` to compute the median in matlab.